# Cleaning up portal_setup

Tags: plone, genericsetup

Is it ok to delete old import profiles in portal_setup.

Currently I have site with many many entries dating back to 2009::

```
 import-all-profile-Products.Archetypes_Archetypes-20090424091904.log External Editor
```

I believe this should not affect site performance, but it would be nice to tidy things up if this is useless data.

Answer (score 2):

It is indeed okay to delete these. :-) They just contain the log output of your GS import runs.